# How to make google sheets export as json

Tags: javascript, json, excel, google-sheets

The data in my google sheet it pretty huge and need to export it as a json format.

I need it in the following structure/example:

```
{
    "name":"bob"
    "timeDateOfUsage": [*google sheet data*]
}
```

So currently I have 2 columns in my google sheet. I need both columns to come in the list in the 'timeDateOfUsage' key in the json structure.. any ideas?

So basically it would look something like this:

```
{
    "name":"bob"
    "timeDateOfUsage": ["*google column1, row 1 value":"google column2, row 1 value","google column1,row2 value":"google column2, row 2 value", "googlecolumn1,row3 value":"goolglecolumn2,row 3 value"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean for your `timeOfDateUsage` array to contain objects (it is invalid as-is), and that your data is in columns `A` and `B`, if you don't mind using some helper columns, you can fill down column `C` with a formula to build the objects for the array:

```
="{" & CHAR(34) & A1 & CHAR(34) & ":" & CHAR(34) & B1 & CHAR(34) & "}"
```

And then in column `D` (or anywhere) `JOIN` them into a JSON object:

```
="{" & CHAR(34) & "name" & CHAR(34) & ":" & CHAR(34) & "bob" & CHAR(34) & "," & CHAR(34) & "timeDateOfUsage" & CHAR(34) & ":" & "[" & JOIN(",", FILTER(C:C, NOT(C:C = ""))) & "]" & "}"
```